# How can i calculate this combinations sum?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, permutations, combinations, binomial-coefficients

$C(n,2)+2×C(n,3)+3×C(n,4)+...+(n-1)×C(n,n)$

By calculating the combinations and multiplying , then simplifying i can until here:

$(n-1)[n/2 + n(n-2)/3 + n(n-2)(n-3)/8 +...+ 1]$

I thought of transforming everything in the brackets to combinations of $n-2$ or $n$ and get something like $(2^n-2)×(n-1)$ but couldnt figure out how.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: just split $\sum (k-1)C(n,k)=\sum kC(n,k)-\sum C(n,k)$.

Comment: Its more of a hint i guess. Mines slightly different

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.